# TypeError: 'WDL' object does not support indexing

Tags: python

I am trying to parser some wdl files into different formats. I have three different parsers and this is part of my code:

```
dlschedule_logger.info (f"Attempt to convert WDL file name = {infile}")
wdl = []
if dlType == "tdms":
    wdl = tdms2dss_convert(config, infile, False)
    
if dlType == "ldms":
    wdl = tdms2dss_convert(config, infile, False)

if dlType == "stdDL":
    wdl = extract_wdl2json(config, infile)

try: 
    wdl[0]['start_time']
except TypeError:
    dlschedule_logger.exception("WDL file is not converted")
```

I have an error happening with this traceback:

```
    start_time_str = wdl[0]['start_time']
TypeError: 'WDL' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The traceback you have shown cannot originate from the code you have shown.